# How to fill a shape in photoshop and avoid white lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fill, painting, borders

This is something it will be useful for several things now that I started "photoshoping" - so I made some lines with the pen tool, then right clicked with the 'direct selection' and then 'stroke path' to paint the lines.

Now, this lines are closed, they make a shape, if I paint the inside with the bucket tool it creates white spaces inbetween the border and the filling!

How does one fill properly in photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you right click to "Stroke Path" there's also a function to "Fill Path" you could use it. I suggest using it first.

Alternatively you can Right Click to Fill the Path then go to Layer > Layer Style > Stroke and this will give you much more control over the stroke.

There's rarely ever a reason to use the Paintbucket in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of anti-aliasing; pixels of lighter colors are generated along edges in order to make it look smooth. The paint bucket doesn't fill those other colors, just the empty pixels.

There are so many ways to do this! Since you already discovered the paint bucket, here is a simple way using the same tool:

Before you click to fill with the bucket, while it's selected, locate in the top menu a place named "Tolerance". Increase the value. Too little won't make a difference, too much will fill the whole screen. You should have that option if you're on CS5+, not sure about earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

For people who may still be finding this issue I discovered that if you set the tolerance to 0 and click the paint bucket a few times (2 to 3 clicks seems to do the trick for me when working with a hard brush and a resolution of 300) it fills the anti aliasing line without adding an ugly edge  to the outside of the original line. (If you have a soft brush or an artistic brush with edge it may not work as well.)

This is much faster than testing out multiple tolerance levels to find some perfect match or trying to use the magic wand with `select`>`modify`>`expand`.

The other option is to toss a layer below the current art layer and clean up the art by quickly painting in the color to fill the gap.

I hope it helps, good luck with your art!

Answer (score 0):

Turn selection into work path, Then stroke path.Then pathfill or bucked twice this is the other option all previous options are valid

Answer (score 0):

what I do is select everything apart from what you want coloured then inverse the selection and use the paintbrush tool (any size, probably use 5000) to fill it in! it's really quick and simple